# How do I connect to an RDS defined under "Resources" in serverless.yml from a Lambda function?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Say I have a section in my `serverless.yml` like this:

```
resources: 
  Resources:
    RDSCluster:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
      Properties:
        MasterUsername: SomeUserName
        MasterUserPassword: SomePassword
        DatabaseName: SomeDatabaseName
        Engine: aurora
        EngineMode: serverless
        ScalingConfiguration:
          AutoPause: true
          MaxCapacity: 16
          MinCapacity: 2
          SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300
```

How can my Lambda functions written in node.js connect to this database, i.e. what is the hostname/ip and where/how can I capture it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cloudformation's `GetAtt` function to access the return value from the DBCluster creation:

```
provider:
  environment:
    RDS:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ RDSCluster, Endpoint.Address ]
```

Now you can access the RDS FQDN (hostname+domain name) in the node.js code like so:

```
console.log(process.env.RDS);
// mystack-mydb-1apw1j4phylrk.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

You can see more about the Cloudformation return values for DBCluster resources here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#aws-properties-rds-database-instance-return-values